# Java: Does Chronicle Map support different value classes?

Tags: java, value-type, chronicle-map

I usually create a new [Chronicle Map](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8x5vA2aLNAhXJNSYKHSI_BzcQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FOpenHFT%2FChronicle-Map&usg=AFQjCNFZLuPyyn8ds6aS0LKt1aMbE_R14Q&sig2=hxTy7wNmwBz4VBxrIjAvTA&bvm=bv.124272578,d.eWE) using a [`ChronicleMapBuilder`](http://static.javadoc.io/net.openhft/chronicle-map/3.8.0/net/openhft/chronicle/map/ChronicleMapBuilder.html) like so:

```
ChronicleMapBuilder<SomeKey, MyImplClass> builder
        = ChronicleMapBuilder.of(SomeKey.class, MyImplClass.class);

ChronicleMap<SomeKey, MyImplClass> map
        = builder.constantKeySizeBySample(someKey)
                 .averageValue(someValue)
                 .entries(myCollection.size())
                 .createPersistedTo(myFile);
```

Does Chronicle Map support the storage of instances of different value classes and if so, how do I build that map?

For example:

```
ChronicleMapBuilder<SomeKey, MyInterfaceThatHasManyDifferentImplementations> builder
        = // .. now what?
```

Basically, I have only one key class - a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). But this date can (or at least, I want it to) be mapped to different implementations of a common interface. I consider myself lucky to have a common interface, but if it is possible to build a Chronicle Map even without a common interface, please advise.

I am sorry I do not currently have the ability to test Chronicle Map's support for different value classes nor am I able to find this documented in any shape or form on the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ChronicleMapBuilder#of](http://static.javadoc.io/net.openhft/chronicle-map/3.8.0/net/openhft/chronicle/map/ChronicleMapBuilder.html#of-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-) takes two `Class` arguments. In the worst case, you can use `Object.class` was your value class (the second argument), and store whatever values you want in the map.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Why do the builder want my class argument to begin with? Surely they will exercise tons of Reflection vodoo on it. But I never really understood why as I do specify average value size with a real sample.

Comment: After closer examination (real life testing) I found you to be right.

Comment: @MartinAndersson "Why do the builder want my class argument to begin with?" is actually an interesting question. ChronicleMapBuilder requires for key/value class objects primarily to check if there are optimized serializers predefined for these classes (namely for boxed primitives, String, CharSequence, [value interfaces](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Values), etc.). "Reflection vodoo" is done only if the key/value class is a value interface.